# Split MP3 track into words

Tags: audio, automation, mp3

I need to split many MP3 tracks into separate words. I want to turn one MP3 track into several tracks containing one word each. I need to do this automatically, because there will be so many tracks.

[Audacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_%28audio_editor%29) is a little dumb for this so I'm looking for something smarter. Additionally, it would be cool if I could type in the words that I know are in the soundtrack to help the computer split it.

How might I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows XP Pro(FOREVER!), but I have Windows 7 too on other computer.

Comment: That is going to be very, very hard. In real speech, you know there aren't actually breaks between words - that most of the time, the sounds run straight into each other?

Answer (score 4):

Trying to split an audio file based on some type of speech recognition, and comparing with contents of a text file is going to be quite an arduous task.

If there are sufficient pauses (silent sections) between the words, you could use this to split up the file into sections. For example in Audacity, go to `Edit -> Clip Boundaries -> Detach at Silence` [[1]](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Edit_Menu:_Clip_Boundaries#disjoin). However this will only split at absolute silence, which is impossible to get while recording. You will need to make use of a filter such as [Noise Gate](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Nyquist_Effect_Plug-ins#Noise_Gate) to zero the audio during these segments.

Comment: I'll try but I don't think this will work well because speech is fast enough so it has to be advanced.

Comment: No it did not work. There's not really silence. This track is recorded by a professional voice actor and gaps between words are really small.

Comment: You could try an [automated cue sheet editor](http://cuemaster.org/) with a [cue sheet splitter](http://www.medieval.it/cuesplitter-pc/menu-id-71.html), but I imagine you would run into the same problem.

Comment: I'll see what it is when I get up and report results.

Comment: No it's even worse.